# How to prove this limit properly?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

If $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} a_n=1$ and $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} b_n=\infty$ then $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} (a_n)^{b_n}=\exp{(\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} (a_n-1)b_n)}$

I have seen a proof, where $\log{(x+1)}=x+o(x)$ were used. But if I used $\log{(x+1)}=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x)$, i would not get the same answer.

Comment: Can you please add the proof?

Comment: When you have a seen a proof then what is the point of your question? Do you seek alternative proof? If that's the case then frankly speaking there is no other essentially different proof. The result is equivalent to the formula $\log(1+x)=x+o(x)$. Also note that $\log(1+x)=x-(x^{2}/2)+o(x)$ implies $\log(1+x)=x+o(x)$ so even this should work fine. Perhaps you made some calculation mistake.

Comment: @gbox Yes, here it is: https://imgur.com/a/FDYoG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT.- $$(a_n)^{b_n}=\left(1+(a_n-1)\right)^{\dfrac{b_n(a_n-1)}{a_n-1}}=\left(1+(a_n-1)\right)^{\frac{1}{a_n-1}\cdot b_n(a_n-1)}$$ Thus 
$$(a_n)^{b_n}\to e^{\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n(a_n-1)}$$ The existence of the limit depends on $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n(a_n-1)$.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, I think.
But the "a-1" shouldn't be "a_n-1"?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes it is, it was a typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be asking for a proof of something that is not true. If $a_n = 1+1/n$ for all $n,$ and $b_n = n$ for odd $n$ and $b_n = n^2$ for even $n,$ then $a_n \to 1,$ and $b_n \to \infty.$ But $\lim a_n^{b_n}$ does not exist: As $n\to \infty$ through odd $n,$ $a_n^{b_n} \to e.$ And if  $n\to \infty$ through even $n,$ then $a_n^{b_n} \to \infty.$

Comment: Could the OP be omitting the phrase, "provided the limit exists"?

Comment: @BarryCipra: agree, but I guess this answer tries to highlight that in these topics one must not omit such phrases. For most beginners such topics are already very confusing and it is better to be precise to avoid any confusion.